# Shadowbox: Do not maintain ratio on resize

Tags: javascript, shadowbox

Basically I want my shadowbox height and width adjustments to be independent of each other, so that the default ratio is not maintained.

Example:

This is what I would like to happen,

[image: shadowbox example]

My shadowbox window default size is 600x400, the browser window is 200x600.
Currently shadowbox will change to aprx 200x130.
I do not want the ratio maintained so I want my shadowbox window sized to 200x400.

I've spent a while searching for solutions online and nothing has come up yet, I'm also fiddling with shadowbox.js but thought I'd ask, this must be a common issue.

I'm using v3.0.3 with jQuery for Images, External sites and pages, Inline and/or dynamic HTML.

Cheers

Answer (score 0):

Easier than I thought...

```
handleOversize: "drag"
```

Reading the [options page](http://www.shadowbox-js.com/options.html) implies that this setting only works for images but that's not the case...